# Why does my inherited static property not hold a value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I'm building an ORM for a project I'm doing. I have two classes in the ORM, `BaseModel` and `SessionLink`, and a function external to them both attempting to use them. `BaseModel` is, well, the base model - a model from which other models inherit so that I can define common behaviour. `SessionLink` is one of those inherited models.

I'd like to be able to chain query methods from `BaseModel`, using an inherited model. Something like this:

```
SessionLink.join("a table").where({some: "conditions"}).get()
```

In order to do that, I need to have a static property on `BaseModel` to store the query that's being built up through the chained methods. So far so good. I've put that static property in with a getter and a setter.

```
class BaseModel {
  static get queryBuilder() {
    return this._query || null;
  }

  static set queryBuilder(val) {
    this._query = val;
  }

  static join(table) {
    if (this.queryBuilder) {
      // Add to existing query
      this.queryBuilder = this.queryBuilder.addJoin(table);
    }
    else {
      // Create a new query, store it in queryBuilder
      this.queryBuilder = new Query().addJoin(table);
    }
  }

  static where(conditions) {
    // Implementation similar to .join
  }

  static get() {
    // Actually send the query to the database and return results
    magicallyGetDatabaseConnection().sendQuery(this.queryBuilder);
  }
}
```

`SessionLink` simply inherits from `BaseModel` (`class SessionLink extends BaseModel`) and adds a couple of model-specific details that are irrelevant to this question.

The problem I'm hitting is this: `queryBuilder` doesn't hold its value. I can run `this.queryBuilder = new Query(...)` from `join` or `where` or wherever, and then log the value of `this.queryBuilder` *on the next line* and it comes back as `null`. In other words:

```
static join(table) {
  if (this.queryBuilder) {
    // Add to existing query
    this.queryBuilder = this.queryBuilder.addJoin(table);
  }
  else {
    // Create a new query, store it in queryBuilder
    this.queryBuilder = new Query().addJoin(table);

    console.log(this.queryBuilder); // null
  }
}
```

Why is this? How do I fix it?

Comment: It appears that `Query.addJoin` is returning something other than the Query instance. Try splitting that line up, e.g `this.queryBuilder = new Query(); this.queryBuilder.addJoin(table)`

Comment: based on the alleged output, it does seem that `new Query().addJoin(table);` returns `null`

Comment: Ugh. You're right, of course, @RobM. - I'm being dumb, looking in the wrong place, and missing the fact that I failed to add a `return this` to the end of `addJoin`. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by not instantiating and calling `addJoin` in one line:

```
this.queryBuilder = new Query()
this.queryBuilder.addJoin(table)
```

Or by returning `this` from your `addJoin()` method

```
class Query {
   addJoin(table) {
      // existing code
      return this
   }
}
```